# Input fields are getting pre-populated with a const value even when there is no query-parameter in url

Tags: http, caching, browser, browser-cache, query-string

I wrote a code where the first screen will accept a query-parameter from URL and pre-populate the respective input field. say

**<-----url------->?qparam=1234** - this will populate **1234** in input field

**<-----url------->?qparam=5678** - this will populate **5678** in input field

But now what happening is if I sent no query-parameter.

**<-----just-url------->**   - then still a constant value is getting populated say **1234**.

Assuming that the same constant value (1234) is used multiple times as query-parameter, I tried checking if it is getting populated from the cache. I hit the same URL (without any query-parameters) in incognito mode but still, the same value populated.

I checked and that value is not hard-coded anywhere.
and 
Note- when I again hit the URL with different query-parameter say

**<-----url------->?qparam=1122** - this populates **1122** in input field as expected.

but again when this is hit **<-----just-url------->** - then again the constant value is getting populated here **1234**.

what could be the reason? if it's cache-related please explain explicitly? also if possible tell if there is any other way to test if the value is getting fetched from the cache?

Thanks in Advance!